# Open sets, intersection and union in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis

If possible, I need to give examples of the following situations:

1) A set of open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ such that the intersection equals $$ \left\{ x \in \mathbb{C} | \mid |x| \leq 1 \right\}$$ and 2) a set of open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ such that the union equals $$ \left\{ x \in \mathbb{C} | \mid |x| \leq 1 \right\}. $$

I think 1) is impossible, since a set of open sets can never have a closed set as an intersection? I want to somehow use the theorem that the union of open sets is open, but I'm not sure if this applies in this context?

Comment: Your first claim is not true. We can consider the intersection of the open intervals $(-1/n,1/n)$ which have a closed intersection.

Comment: In $\mathbb{C}$ and several other spaces (separable metrizable), __every__ closed set is a countable intersection of open sets.

Comment: The intersection of a *finite* set of open sets is open, but you can achieve very different types of sets when intersecting (or joining) a countably infinite set of sets.

Answer (score 3):

$A$ is the set of open balls $B(0,1+1/n)$.

Answer (score 1):

You are right on 2. The union of open sets is open and so it can't equal the closed circle with radius $1$, which is not open (prove directly, or use the fact that in $\mathbb{C}$ the only subsets that are both open and closed are $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{C}$, because it is connected).

You're wrong on 1: the intersection of open sets can be closed. Just consider the open balls with center $0$ and radius $1+1/n$ (for $n>0$).

Comment: Ok, thanks. What about the converse? Let's say I have an open set $A$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Can I have then have a set of closed subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ such that the intersection equals $A$?

Comment: @Kamil The intersection of closed subsets is closed.